# How do I loop through JavaScript code with Blade passing PHP variables

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-blade

I am using chart.js to show some data, and everything was working fine when the code was this:

JavaScript/Blade

```
 var pieDataAssignments = [

                @for($i = 0;$i<count($name);$i++)

            {
                value: {!! count(array_filter($ass_c,create_function('$a','return $a=="'.$name[$i].'";')))!!},
                color: 'pink',
                highlight: "#eaa5a2",
                label: 'Subject'
            },

                @endfor

        ];
```

Then I thought it was working, which it was, and I thought to start customising the Pie Chart.

Firstly I tried inserting the value for each variable individually, e.g.

```
color: {!! $colour[$i] !!},
etc...
```

That just prevented the pie chart from appearing, which led me to ponder my failure..

I then tried to insert everything into the first Blade call, like so:

Blade

```
{!!'

{
    value:'.count(array_filter($ass_c,create_function('$a','return $a=="'.$name[$i].'";'))).',
    color: "'.$colour[$i].'",
    highlight: "#eaa5a2",
    label: "hi"
},

'!!}
```

But still, it did not show up.

How can I go about looping JavaScript code and passing php variables at the same time? I don't know what else to try and I can't find anything online apart from telling me to do exactly what I tried.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you provide (at least an excerpt) of the rendered javascript code? I think at the very least inspecting that could lead you to see where the issue is

Comment: I just solved it, by doing exactly what you said, thank you @watcher, I'll remember this next time something doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, the code I had was recreating the array inside it's own instance. The code that now works is the following:

```
var pieDataAssignments = [

        @for($i = 0;$i<count($name);$i++)

        {!!'

        {
            value:'.count(array_filter($ass_c,create_function('$a','return $a=="'.$name[$i].'";'))).',
            color: "'.$colour[$i].'",
            highlight: "#eaa5a2",
            label: "'.$name[$i].'"
        },

        '!!}



        @endfor

];
```